# Which hashing algorithm shoud l use for a safe file checksum?

Tags: security, hash, md5, sha1, checksum

For my work i'll need to provide my customer a specific file which will be the result of the work i have done for them.

To protect the integrity of the work i have done and to guarantee it has never been modified, i intend to add a checksum to my documentation which will be provided with the file.

Since MD5 and SHA-1 are not secure for a long time now, i was wondering if we were still using them for this purpose or is there are better algorithm which could do the same job but safer.

I'm looking for the best reliable solution. I'm aware that a 100% proof will never be possible but i was wondering if MD5 was still rated "good" for this purpose or if there are really new and safer tools.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not programming related. This belongs on security.stackexchange.com. That said, currently the correct choice is going to be SHA-256 or SHA-512. Unless you have a very specialized problem and know exactly what you're doing, there are no other cryptographic hashes you should consider today. (Note, however, that if you ship the hash with the file, the attacker can just change the documentation as well. You probably want signing, not hashing.)

Comment: Your scheme has no security at all, no matter what hash function you use. Pay attention to @RobNapier parenthetical sentence at the end of his comment. Rob, don't bury the lead!